# javascript automation using selenium

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I am a newcomer to Javascript automation using Mocha framework and Selenium web driver. I am trying to automate the Gmail website with the following code but constantly getting an error. The code and error are as follows:

```
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome'),
var driver = new webdriver.builder().withCapabilities({‘browserName’ : ‘chrome’}).build();
{ describe , before , after , it }  require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');
test.describe( 'Test Suite' , function(){

    test.before(function(){
        driver.get( "https:gmail.com" );
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("signInName")).sendKeys("Prashvenky@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("next")).click();
    });

    test.after(function(){
        driver.quit();
    });

    test.it( 'Test Case' , function(){
        driver.getTitle().then(function(title){
            expect(title).equals(my_title);
        })

        driver.sleep();
    });
    });
```

and error I am getting is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:20:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:33:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:431:19)
    at singleRun (C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:125:15)
    at exports.runMocha (C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:190:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:362:11)
    at C:\Users\Prashanth.v\mochatest\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:241:49
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Can someone please help me in this regard?.

Thanks and Regardsm
V.Prashnth

Comment: `, var` looks like a typo? Consider changing it to `; var`? - In face there are multiple syntax errors, may you fix those? Stuff like `it }  require` and `{ describe` is missing a keyword

Comment: can you please elaborate and say, I am not able to understand.. at least the line number will do please

Comment: The first typo is on line 1. Consider using a "linting" tool like eslint to help point out errors in syntax?

Comment: Yes got it!..thanks!